# is there a library can work with input file that contains descriptions and values?

Tags: c++, boost, input, file-io

i'm looking for a library that can do the following :

- ask questions and generate an input file
- read that input file
- while reading the modified input file, the lib assigns the value into the program accordingly to the description in the input file.

i wrote a simple program that does it, like this:

```
>./main
gaussian width:2
```

here the program cout "gaussian width" and i input "2". the program also generates parameters.txt file:

```
gaussian width:2
```

i can start the program with an existing file:

```
>./main parameters.txt
```

it reads the parameter "2" from parameter file and assigns it to `int gaussianWidth` within the program.

I couldn't find anything like that on the web, so i'm almost done writing one. but i'mm wondering if there is an elegant library like that, for example in boost.

Comment: i already looked at boost::program_option. it works with options not input files. the file would contain around 50 lines with a format "description:value". and i'm looking for smtn that i don't have to modify

Comment: erm, you can use input files for `program_options`, have a very close look at their examples. Your file is already almost there, all you need to do is replace the ":" with a "=" and it will work, a simple search and replace will take care of that.

Comment: Here is the section about configuration files: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/program_options/overview.html#id2074347

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is [program options from boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/program_options.html). However you may need to adapt your input file.